# Htaccess редирект

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

Всем привет,

Вопрос заключается в следующем:

Как правильно сделать через mod rewrite редирект с subdomain.site.ru/$1 на www.site.ru/$1
При условии, что редирект будет срабатывать если запрашиваемая страница не /need/ ? То есть если обращение к странице /need/, то мы остаемся на поддомене, а в остальных других случаях уходим на www.site.ru/$1 ?

Пробовал по-разному, но в основном у меня возникала 500 ошибка, по причине того, что не хватает знаний. 
:(

Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь у вас есть в первой строке htaccess код

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Можно сделать так 
    Redirect /ssilka.php http://site.ru

Answer (score 0):

Может уже не актуально)

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то возможно это поможет. Я делал редирект всех запросов на site.ru в папку /folder/, только если не запрошена сама /folder/, т.е. исключил зацикливание.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Следовательно, в вашем случае требуется что-то в виде:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/need/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1    [L,R=301]
```